# match only first "not used" occurrence of a value between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Having two table with same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
    Id INT, 
    Name VARCHAR(256), 
    Value DECIMAL(18,2), 
    LineId INT
); 

CREATE TABLE Table2 
(
    Id INT, 
    Name VARCHAR(256), 
    Value DECIMAL(18,2), 
    LineId INT
);
```

Is there a way to match only the first "not used" occurrence of the record based on their columns:

```
Table1.ID = Table2.Id AND Table1.Value = Table2.Value
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 'aaaaa', 100, 1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 'bbbb', 50, 2);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 'cccc', 100, 3);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 'dddd', 5, 4);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 'ffff', 100, 5);

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(1, 'ddd', 40, 1);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(1, 'eee', 100, 2);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 'ffff', 5, 3)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(1, 'fff', 100, 4);
```

The result should be :

```
(1, 'aaaaa', 100 , 'eee',1);
(1, 'bbbb', 50, null,2);
(1, 'cccc', 100, 'fff',3);
(1, 'dddd', 5, 'fff',4);
(1, 'ffff', 100, null,5);
```

I've tried using a LEFT JOIN [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7443f/3) but this creates a cartesian product :

```
SELECT
    t1.Id AS id, 
    t1.Name AS NameT1, 
    t1.Value AS ValueT1, 
    t2.Name AS fromName,
    t1.LineID AS LineId
FROM
    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.Value = t2.Value
ORDER BY
    t1.LineId;
```

Comment: What does "not used" mean?

Comment: meaning that when a row from Table2 is matched , to be considered as "used" and to be skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a row number on the fly for each dataset and pair rows according to value+rownumber. For example:

```
select x.id, x.name, x.value, y.name, x.lineid
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id, value order by lineid) as rn 
  from table1 t
) x
left join (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id, value order by lineid) as rn
  from table2 t
) y on y.id = x.id and y.value = x.value and y.rn = x.rn
order by x.name
```

Result:

```
 id  name   value   name  lineid 
 --- ------ ------- ----- ------ 
 1   aaaaa  100.00  eee   1      
 1   bbbb   50.00   null  2      
 1   cccc   100.00  fff   3      
 1   dddd   5.00    ffff  4      
 1   ffff   100.00  null  5
```

Comment: I *think* he wants to have partition by ID not Value judging by the question

Comment: @siggemannen That may be true, but it's difficult to tell since all rows have the same id. Nevertheless, I added the partition by id as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cqan use a CTE with a ROW_NUMBER to get your wanted results, further you need als to get rid of the croos join add anonther condition to your join

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE AS
(select t1.Id as id, 
t1.Name as NameT1, 
t1.Value as ValueT1, 
t2.Name as fromName,
t1.LineID as LineId,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.Name,t1.Value ORDER BY  t2.LineID) rn
from Table1 t1
LEFT join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Value = t2.Value AND 
t1.LineID < t2.LineID
)
SELECT id , NameT1,     ValueT1,    fromName ,  LineId
FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
order by LineId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7443f/9/0)**:

```
| id | NameT1 | ValueT1 | fromName | LineId |
|----|--------|---------|----------|--------|
|  1 |  aaaaa |     100 |      eee |      1 |
|  1 |   bbbb |      50 |   (null) |      2 |
|  1 |   cccc |     100 |      fff |      3 |
|  1 |   dddd |       5 |   (null) |      4 |
|  1 |   ffff |     100 |   (null) |      5 |
```